# Event Delegation Performance in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, delegates

I have read about event delegation concept in Javascript. Instead of attaching event to every child node we can bind event to the parent. I tried to measure the timings in traditional and delegated scenario.

[With Delegation](http://jsfiddle.net/dtg9e5L7/)

[Traditional](http://jsfiddle.net/LydvkwLv/)

**HTML**

```
<ul id="list">
    <li id="1">Item #1</li>
    <li id="2">Item #2</li>
    <li id="3">Item #3</li>
    <li id="4">Item #4</li>
    <li id="5">Item #5</li>
    <li id="6">Item #6</li>
    <li id="7">Item #7</li>        
    <li id="8">Item #8</li>
</ul>
```

**Delegation**

```
document.getElementById('list').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var T1 = window.performance.now();
    console.log(window.performance.now()-T1);
});
```

**Traditional**

```
document.getElementById('1').addEventListener('click',function(){
    var T1 = window.performance.now();
    console.log(window.performance.now()-T1);
});
document.getElementById('2').addEventListener('click',function(){
    var T1 = window.performance.now();
    console.log(window.performance.now()-T1);
});
```

The timing for listening an event in case of delegation is higher compared to the case where an event is directly binded to the child node. See the console for results. The reason for this which I thought is that the event bubbles and reaches the parent node and takes time compared to where it is captured at the child node directly.

Am I correct? Delegation is laggy? Low bandwidth users will have a bad UX?

Comment: "Low bandwidth users?" No, bandwidth doesn't effect events once the page has loaded. Low CPU users, perhaps.

Comment: What if event fires an XHR request and manipulates the DOM. Delegation takes time to fire followed by low network causing delay in getting XHR response and showing effects late?

Comment: The time spent on network I/O is going to be much longer than the time spent dispatching events, regardless of the mechanism you use (unless you have a very unusually slow browser and very unusually fast network).

Comment: assuming network I/O to be same for both the cases, is delegation slower?